# Automatic update a Windows application

Tags: c#, auto-update

How do I develop my Windows application so it will auto update on the client machine, like Firefox, [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype), etc.?

Is there any simple approach or any open source library which help me to do it just following some steps or a few lines of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-update library for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) is what you're searching for.

You might also find these SO questions interesting (which offers some different solutions):

- [Auto update for WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139266/auto-update-for-winforms-application)
- [How do I implement an auto update strategy for my in-house winform app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365062/how-do-i-implement-an-auto-update-strategy-for-my-in-house-winform-app)

Comment: Here is an article against ClickOnce
http://www.stevestreeting.com/2013/05/12/friends-dont-let-friends-use-clickonce/

Comment: Another drawback of ClickOnce is that it can only update user (not machine-wide) installations. For a list of available update frameworks, you may find https://omaha-consulting.com/best-update-frameworks-for-windows interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The most popular frameworks are:

- [Google Omaha](https://github.com/google/omaha) - This is what Chrome uses. Very powerful.
- [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) - This is used in Electron applications. Easy to use but can't update machine-wide installations. Also, no graphical update notifications.
- [WinSparkle](https://winsparkle.org/) - Gives you graphical update notifications. But less mature than Squirrel.
- [AutoUpdater.NET](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET) - Both graphical and silent updates. Similar to Squirrel and WinSparkle.

I've taken these links from [this article](https://omaha-consulting.com/best-update-framework-for-windows-10-7). It goes into more details about the pros and cons of each of the frameworks.

Comment: The last link no longer works for me.

Comment: I fixed the link @jordanz.

Answer (score 3):

try microsoft [clickonce](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/ClickOnce-Deployment.aspx) technology

(in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wyupdate/) or [.NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use MD5-Update it easy only need add 5 lines at your application, no configuration need in your app only add library and publish the files.

[image: MD5-Update]

**1. Your need a web server with PHP** for publish your files please include updt.exe.

[image: WebServer]

**2. Add index.php** for make list of update files. aviable on github repository https://github.com/jrz-soft-mx/MD5-Update/blob/main/Tools/Tools.zip o create new app with this code.

```
<?php
$_dat = array();
$_dir=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($_dir) as $_itm) {
    $_fil = str_replace(".".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $_itm);
    if(!is_dir($_fil) && $_fil != "index.php"){     
        $_dat[]=array('StrFil' => "$_fil", 'StrMd5' => strtoupper(md5_file($_fil)), 'lonSiz' => filesize($_fil));
    }
}
echo json_encode($_dat, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

[image]

**3. Add nuget repository** at your proyect

```
PM> Install-Package MD5.Update
```

**4. Call the library** when your app stars, with your update folder url, update all files and download your new app on updt folder, for replace your app need updt.exe

```
string strUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/app/";
if (MD5Update.MD5Update.Check(strUrl, true))
{
    Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"updt.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + " " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

[image]

[image]

**5. updt.exe** for replace the current app with the new app updt folder to app. aviable on github repository https://github.com/jrz-soft-mx/MD5-Update/blob/main/Tools/Tools.zip o create new app with this code.

```
try
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    List<string> lisArg = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList();
    if (lisArg.Count < 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please provide App Excutable Name and Procees name");
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    string strAppName = lisArg[1];
    string strAppProcees = lisArg[2];
    Process[] lisPro = Process.GetProcessesByName(strAppProcees);
    foreach (Process Pro in lisPro)
    {
        if (Pro.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        {
            Pro.Kill();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    string strAppMain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + strAppName;
    string strAppUpdate = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"updt\" + strAppName;
    if (!File.Exists(strAppMain))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App Excutable dosent exists");
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    if (!File.Exists(strAppUpdate))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App Excutable Updated dosent exists");
        Application.Exit();
        return;
    }
    File.Copy(strAppUpdate, strAppMain, true);
    long fileSize = 0;
    FileInfo currentFile = new FileInfo(strAppMain);
    while (fileSize < currentFile.Length)
    {
        fileSize = currentFile.Length;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        currentFile.Refresh();
    }
    Process.Start(strAppMain);
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred");
    File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"updt_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")  + " .txt", Ex.ToString());
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Try this package its easy and works great.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Update Block in the Ent Lib by msft.

Answer (score 0):

How about System Center 2012 Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add another possible variation:

https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate

https://github.com/cecon/autoupdatereasy

https://github.com/NetSparkleUpdater/NetSparkle

Answer (score 0):

While ClickOnce is simple and it resurrected for .NET 5, it still has a lot of limitations, so I found out that nowadays better option exists: you could use included in Windows 10 mechanism for app delivery called AppInstaller by packaging your app in MSIX bundle or package.

I covered my findings related to the topic in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636323/3087417)