# VS setup project installer - Auto updates

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, setup-project

Long time ago I created a Window Service program that was installed via "setup project installer".
It's a "project template" used to create a msi file /setup.exe .

Since I wasn't enough experienced back then, the way I implemented auto-updates was by running a task daily to check for newer versions on my server.
When I have a newer version, I would usually make the Window Service:

1. Download the update files
2. Run an EXE program that was apart of the update files
3. The EXE stops the service first, puts the files in the program's folder and starts the service again.

If any error happens during the update, the EXE logs that, reverts the old files back, and starts the Window Service.

So far, the "manual" auto-updates is working fine, but I didn't know if there was an option to add auto-updates via "setup project installer".

Is such option available in the setup project installer?

If there is, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not built in support in the setup project template but there are other free options.

If you are not keen to building an MSI you could use Clickonce. (*I don't recommend it but it is an option*).

You can also use other free frameworks that provide auto-updates support for desktop applications, don't reinvent the wheel. Here are more details:

- [Automatic update a Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769615/automatic-update-a-windows-application)

You also have the option of using commercial tools (like Advanced Installer or InstallShield). These provide you with built-in support for updates for your MSI/EXE packages, much easy to configure and integrate.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*